# How to design a DynamoDB index that has 4 filters in the UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

I am trying to design an index that can respond to my access pattern.
In the UI, I have one collection that can be filtered by 4 attributes:

- customer
- date
- type
- creditor

I was reading the documentation and Alex Debrie's book, and I was inclined to use the Composite Sort Key strategy for filtering. Even though, I have a problem: I can filter my data combining any of these attributes. For example:

- I can only fill the customer and date filter
- Or just select type as a filter
- Or just select date as a filter
- etc (All combination of filters)

If I had the 4 filters, I would just use the pattern `date#type#customer#creditor` and it would work. But how can I design these indexes in order to have the flexibility of multiple filters, but not all of them are needed.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. If you use `date#type#customer#creditor` as a composite sort key, how would you filter bu type?

Comment: @jellycsc That combination will work if and only if the 4 attributes are required. This is exactly my main point and biggest problem, thus, it doesn't work for me. I want to know how to do that :)

Comment: Ok, i see. In general, ddb is not good at this type of work. But it can still achieve it if you create a GSI for each of your filter.

Comment: I see! Hum. I feared that I would need to do that. Thanks for the input